# Set div width from text inside of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div like so

```
<div class="hide-show">
    <h3 class="visible-toogle">Hide gallery</h3>
</div>
```

Basically I have attached a click event to this div, so if a user clicks the div something will happen, but here is the problem, if you look at the picture below, the user can click the whole div box,

[image: divbox]

I want to restrict this so the user has to click the text, I.E. the characters themselves, but i don't want them to be able to click the div 400 pixels away from the text. What is the best way to solve this?

--- update ---

I have just updated my html to look like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $( ".visible-toogle" ).click(function() {
            if($(this).text() == "Show gallery")
            {
                $(this).text("Hide gallery");
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).text("Show gallery");
            }
            $( ".galleria" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
            });
        });
    });
```

and html to be like this

```
<h3 class="visible-toogle">Hide gallery</h3>
```

but it still has the same effect like I was targeting the div

Comment: Target the h3, not the div

Comment: ....or set the `.hide-show` to `display:inline-block`

Comment: that works perfectly Paulie_D cheers